# VSCode: How can I make Intellisense work with a vanilla Javascript project?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, jsdoc

I have a `foo.js` file:

```
/**
 * Foo Class
 * @typedef {Object} Foo
 */
function Foo(){
}

Foo.prototype.sayHello = function (){
    alert("Hello!");
};
```

In my `bar.js` file I have:

```
/** @type {Foo} */
var foo = new Foo();
foo.sayHello();
```

but if I type `foo.` Intellisense doesn't suggest `sayHello()`.

This is an old vanilla Javascript project (without npm/node/requirejs etc.), the JS file is just loaded into HTML with:

```
<script src="foo.js"></script>
<script src="bar.js"></script>
```

Is there a way to make Intellisense work with a vanilla Javascript project?

Answer (score 1):

You should have a hint from VSCode on `function Foo()` suggesting to use ES2015 `class` syntax instead. That syntax changes your code to this

```
/**
 * Foo Class
 * @typedef {Object} Foo
 */
class Foo {
  constructor() {
  }
  sayHello() {
    alert("Hello!");
  }
}
```

And hints are provided in the other file as expected.

The same result is yielded, interestingly, by keeping your code as-is and simply removing all JSDoc.

Comment: The same result is yielded, interestingly, by keeping your code as-is and simply removing all JSDoc.